# Django: Add subquery to a nested model

Tags: django, model, nested, django-queryset

I have the following models in my project. An SRV contains many projects, and each project contains several tasks. I am detailing each SRV in a template and showing a list of all associated projects.

```
class Srv(models.Model):
    srv_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class Project(models.Model):
    srv = models.ForeignKey(Srv, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
```

in views.py I want to get the completed tasks associated with each project, but I always get all the tasks associated with all projects from the SRV (main model)

```
class srvdetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Srv
    template_name = 'srv_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

**UPDATE:**

Add a couple of definitions in the Project model and printed them in the template as follows:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    #...

    def todo_done(self):
        return self.todo_set.filter(state=True).count() * 100 / self.todo_set.all().count()

    def todo_left(self):
        return self.todo_set.filter(state=False).count() * 100 / self.todo_set.all().count()
```

In my template:

```
{% for project in srv.project_set.all %}
{{project.todo_done|floatformat:0|intcomma}}% complete
{{project.todo_left|floatformat:0|intcomma}}% left
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for your comments @NKSM

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like?

```py
Todo.objects.filter(
    state = <state>,
    project__srv = <srv_instance>
)
```

## Update:

template.html:

```html
{% for srv in srvs %}
  <div> srv year: {{srv.srv_year}} </div>
  {% for project in srv.project_set.all %}
    <div> project id: {{project.id}} </div>
    {% for todo in project.todo_set.all %}
      {% if todo.state %}
        <div> todo id: {{todo.id}} </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand how to incorporate this into code. I understand that I must get the tasks per project and send it as context for each project listed

Comment: We'll you don't really need to do this in the view - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

in your view:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(todo__state=True)
```

in your template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>srv year</th>
        <th>project ID</th>
        <th>Total number of completed tasks</th>
    </tr>
    {% for project in projects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ project.srv.srv_year }}</td>
        <td>{{ project.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ project.todo_set.count }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% enfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: How can I send this value to each project in the template? the Django system on the cli correctly detects the number of completed tasks per project associated with the SRV

Comment: @Drennos, i have updated my answer. This should be work.

Comment: I managed to send extra content to my template by adding definitions in my model